# Flask install: requirement already satisfied

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to go through [Miguel Grinberg's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/904393/miguel) peerless guide on creating Flask app, but hitting an early error. Can anyone see why?

I've already got an installation of Flask in Anaconda, but I was expecting to be able to install a new installation with a new virtual environment.

I've taken the steps to create a new environment but get the following error when I try to install a new version of Flask.

```
 (venv)xxx:flasky davidelks
 $ pip install Flask
 Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade):
 Flask in /Users/xxx/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

What have I done wrong? Better yet, what can I do to fix it?

Comment: That’s not an error; you already have it installed. Use `--upgrade` to upgrade.

Comment: The problem is that when I try t point my browser to http://127.0.0.1:5000/ it fails.

Comment: Did you start the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not an error. It's just pip's way of telling you "Go on, this is already installed!".

Comment: The problem is that when I try t point my browser to http://127.0.0.1:5000/ it fails.

Comment: Try taking a closer look at the error message when that fails, and if it doesn't work, please post a new question.

Comment: This webpage is not available

ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: I think you're missing a step there. After installing Flask, you should create your app and then run it so the development server will be up.

Comment: @elksie5000 just create a hello world, this is available on internet, just search for it and the run the script and you will get it !!!

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the flask from outside the virtual folder.
For eg: If "virtual" is the name of the virtual folder,then install the flask from outside the virtual folder using the command "virtual\Scripts\pip install flask"

Comment: I dont think your answer solves his problem. He needs to get it installed inside the virtual folder and your answer is to install it outside. Does not help.